# Tweeting from a UIButton inside a tableviewcell - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to trigger this `IBAction` from a `UITableViewCell` subclass which has buttons inside. I can't get the `TWTweetComposeViewController` due to this line of code :

```objc
[self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
```

Is it possible to open a tweet window by pressing the button on the cell?

```objc
- (IBAction)tweetTapped:(id)sender { 
{
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
{
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = 
        [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:
        @"Tweeting from iOS 5 By Tutorials! :)"];
    [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
        initWithTitle:@"Sorry"                                                             
        message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure  
            your device has an internet connection and you have 
            at least one Twitter account setup"                                                          
        delegate:self                                              
        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"                                                   
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
  }

}
```

Comment: is this function get called on pressing the button?

Comment: What do you see? An error? No tweetSheet popping up?

Comment: no tweetsheet popping up. The function is being called. In fact when i tried accessing this method the UIViewController it works. When I tried from the UITableViewCell, the tweet sheet doesn't popup.

Comment: the alert view pops out in the simulator. But not on the device. Is it because the button is declared as a part of the UITableViewCell class. [ self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES]; belongs to UIViewController?

Comment: What class is the code you posted in?

Comment: its posted inside a UITableViewCell. I have the buttons inside the tableviewcell. Am I doing it right?

Comment: No, that's not right.  presentModalViewController is a method of UIViewController, so you can't call that on self from within a UITableViewCell subclass.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to go about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As @rdelmar mentioned, `presentModalViewController` is a method of `UIViewController` not `UITableViewCell` so you shouldn't call `[self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES]` from your subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

Instead your `UITableViewCell` subclass should inform the view controller for its table view (likely a subclass of `UITableViewController`) to present the `tweetSheet`. One way to do this would be to add a delegate to your `UITableViewCell` subclass that is informed whenever the user wants to tweet something. Set this delegate to your `UITableViewController` subclass and have it handle the tweet request by presenting the sheet. The delegate of the enclosing `UITableView` is probably already your `UITableViewController` subclass, so a fast a dirty way to accomplish the same thing may be to do change the line you have to something like the following:

```
[self.superview.delegate presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
```

Note: `presentModalViewController:animated:` is deprecated in iOS 5 and `presentViewController:animated:completion:` is preferred as a direct replacement.